# Multiple level properties with EF Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

After upgrading from .NET 5.0 to .NET 6.0 (including all the relative Microsoft libraries as Entity Framework), I started getting this error when executing a query to my database context using EF Core:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An error was generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.NavigationBaseIncludeIgnored': The navigation 'MarkersTranslation.Marker' was ignored from 'Include' in the query since the fix-up will automatically populate it. If any further navigations are specified in 'Include' afterwards then they will be ignored. Walking back include tree is not allowed. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.NavigationBaseIncludeIgnored' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.

This is the incriminated code:

```cs
Tour tour = await _context.Tours.Include(mpt => mpt.MarkersPerTours)
                                .ThenInclude(mrk => mrk.Marker)
                                .ThenInclude(mrkProp => mrkProp.MarkersTranslations)
                                .ThenInclude(mrk => mrk.Marker)
                                .ThenInclude(mrkTp => mrkTp.Type)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == tourId);
```

So every `Tour` entity has a set of related `Marker` with their translations, but every `Marker` also have a `Type`.

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels) seems to approve the pattern I use for this query in order to include multiple levels.

Which is now the correct way to obtain the same result with EF Core 6?

Comment: Can you show these models? You don't have to show all properties but at least you can show relational properties.

Answer (score 9):

It's interesting that this restriction "Walking back include tree is not allowed" is not in EF core 6's [breaking changes list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes).

The way to include everything you want while only walking the tree forward is this:

```cs
Tour tour = await _context.Tours
    .Include(tour => tour.MarkersPerTours)
        .ThenInclude(mpt => mpt.Marker)
            .ThenInclude(mrk => mrk.MarkersTranslations)
    .Include(tour => tour.MarkersPerTours)
        .ThenInclude(mpt => mpt.Marker)
            .ThenInclude(mrk => mrk.Type)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == tourId);
```

BTW, I changed the names of the range variables, IMO it's clearer, and more conventional, to let the names reflect their types, not the properties they're going to navigate to.

Comment: You are right, it is not included on breaking changes docs. So I've opened an issue (https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/3653) on Microsoft Docs repo. I'm according with you about names that need to reflect types.

Answer (score 6):

Configure warnings to ignore it as below

```
services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options =>
        {
          
            options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings =>
                
            warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.NavigationBaseIncludeIgnored));
        });
```

Or you can add similar things in the **OnConfiguring** method of Dbcontext

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
        .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.NavigationBaseIncludeIgnored, CoreEventId.NavigationBaseIncluded));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "Which is now the correct way to obtain the same result" and only repeats what the exception message tells.

Answer (score 0):

in some case, remove the .Include of entity that is causing the error. This error indicates that the entity does not need to be included